# Mozilla is recording my non-template symfony redirects in the history

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, redirect, mozilla

Consider this scenario: 
I have page1 which contains a link to /page2. where /page2 is a symfony route which doesn't have a template & what it does is redirect to page3 on which we don't have any control.

Now when I press back button on page3 it redirects back to page 2 & page 2 redirects back to page 3 (this happens only in firefox).

What I want is to not save that page route /page2 in the history of firefox.

About what i read so far, chrome doesn't save routes that doensn't have a UI in the history, but firefox does.

Any suggestions on what to do? Can i run some js in page1 to instruct mozilla not to save the /page2 in history?

Comment: what is the status code of /page2, what do you mean by no template? what is the output, is a symfony error thrown on page2 ?   is that really the desired way it should work, what are you trying to archieve with page2 ?

Comment: If `/page2` is making the redirection through javascript this can be the problem, if you do a http 301 redirect it must work AFAIK

Comment: @johnSmith status code is fine.. the purpose of page2 is to prepare information before redirecting to page3, it's just a controller's action which then render's the form from page3.

Comment: @Pipe nope it's not js redirection.. page2 is redirection using symfony inside the action of that particular controller (defined in the route).

Comment: @RahulGupta so why do you redirect instead of return the results of action3 without redirecting=?

Comment: @johnSmith Actually page3 is a login page.. in symfony it's return a form of page3 since i have no control over page 3.. I don't know how it mysteriously redirects & changes the url.. Note: The thing i just want to acheive is to make mozilla not remember the page2's url in the histroy, which chrome & safari are doing by themselves... Any Suggestions?